# C++ expected primary-expression error

Tags: c++

I got a 'expected primary-expression before 'int'' error when compiling with g++ the following code. Do you know why and how to fix it ? Thank you !

```
 struct A
 {
     template <typename T>
     T bar() { T t; return t;}
 };

 struct B : A
 {
 };

 template <typename T>
 void foo(T  & t)
 {
     t.bar<int>();
 }

 int main()
 {
     B b;
     foo(b);
 }
```

Comment: is it the t.bar<in> line that gives you the error?

Answer (score 14):

When compiling the `foo()` function, the compiler doesn't know that bar is a member **template**. You have to tell it that:

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T & t)
{
  t. template bar<int>(); // I hope I put template in the right position
}
```

The compiler thinks that bar is just a member variable, and that you try to compare it with something, e.g. `t.bar < 10`. As a result, it complains that "int" is not an expression.

Comment: @Murilo I bet most C++ programmers don't know it: It's rarely if ever needed so why should one know? I know it exists, but I'm not even sure where the 'template' has to go (but `t.bar template <int>` looks even weirder to me, so I think I got it right).