# Typename C++ error

Tags: c++, forward-declaration, sfinae

Sorry for this very vague title, it's very hard to describe.

The error I'm stuck with is this, I have no idea what it means:

> carray.h:176: error: ‘typename Carray<T, Allocator>::is_iterator’ names ‘template<class T, class Allocator> template<class I, bool check> struct Carray<T, Allocator>::is_iterator’, which is not a type

I have this snippet to detect if something is an iterator and use the correct overload (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6050441/why-does-this-constructor-overload-resolve-incorrectly). This compiles:

```
template<class T> class Carray {
private:
    // uses SFINAE to determine if the passed in type is indeed an iterator
    template<class It>
    class is_iterator_impl {
    private:
        typedef char yes[1];
        typedef char no[2];

        template<class C>
        static yes& _test(typename C::iterator_category*);

        template<class>
        static no& _test(...);
    public:
        static const bool value = sizeof(_test<It>(0)) == sizeof(yes);
    };

    template<class It, bool check = is_iterator_impl<It>::value> struct is_iterator { typedef void type; };
    template<class It> struct is_iterator<It*, false> { typedef void type; };
    template<class It> struct is_iterator<It, false> { };

public:
    template<class It>
    Carray(It first, It last, typename is_iterator<It>::type *dummy = 0) {
        // create array from 2 iterators
    }
};
```

Now I wanted to separate implementation from the declarations, and I tried this, but I got the error:

```
template<class T> class Carray {
private:
    // uses SFINAE to determine if the passed in type is indeed an iterator
    template<class It> class is_iterator_impl;
    template<class It, bool check = is_iterator_impl<It>::value> struct is_iterator { typedef void type; };
    template<class It> struct is_iterator<It*, false> { typedef void type; };
    template<class It> struct is_iterator<It, false> { };
public:
    template<class It> Carray(It first, It last, typename is_iterator<It>::type *dummy = 0);
};

template<class T>
template<class It>
Carray<T>::Carray(It first, It last, typename Carray<T>::is_iterator<It>::type *dummy) {
    // create array from 2 iterators - ERROR IN THIS DEFINITION
}

template<class T>
template<class It>
class Carray<T>::is_iterator_impl {
private:
    typedef char yes[1];
    typedef char no[2];

    template<class C>
    static yes& _test(typename C::iterator_category*);

    template<class>
    static no& _test(...);
public:
    static const bool value = sizeof(_test<It>(0)) == sizeof(yes);
};
```

I'm using g++ 4.5.5.

Comment: I think you have an interesting question somewhere in here, but it is buried in pages and pages of code.  Could you simplify your program down the simplest possible thing that should compile and doesn't, and post the whole thing?  This way we can try compiling the program on our computers.  Also if the compiler gives you an error about a specific line, you should tell us where that line is.

Comment: @David Grayson: Sorry, let me change that :) The problem is that this "hack" really is pages and pages of code :)

Comment: At least a hint in the code as to where the compiler is complaining would be nice.

Comment: David Rodríguez - dribeas, David Grayson: Done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With these type of problems that are somehow *obscure* (i.e. there is quite a bit of code, and it is not simple to read in a first pass) you should provide a working (or rather failing example).

My guess is that you are missing a `template` keyword (`Carray` constructor argument):

```
typename Carray<T, Allocator>::template is_iterator<InputIterator>::type
//                             ^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I cleaned up the code now to pinpoint the problem more.

Comment: Alright, that did it, but I never saw `template` being used like that. Care to explain what it does and why it is needed?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879184/c-expected-primary-expression-error/4879237#4879237 for a short example where this 'template' is needed.

Comment: I checked that post and this was said: "the compiler doesn't know that <member_name> is a member template". But that's not true right? It __does__ know that, because it was declared with `template<>`.

Comment: @nightcracker It is used to mark the difference between een normal member en een member template. For a normal class, a compiler can tell the difference. For a template class, things are complicated so the human has to tell the compiler what is expected.

Comment: @nightcracker: The standard requires the presence of that keyword there. The reason is that prior to instantiation and type substitution the template can be verified for correctness, and it is then when the compiler cannot know what the member is (consider that there could be specializations for different types). If you understand the need for `typename` in the same expression, then `template` is exactly the same, with the only difference that one refers to a type, and the other to a template.

Answer (score -2):

Check out the semicolon at the end of every line, it looks like you have written something like this:

```
template<class T, class Allocator> 
template<class I, bool check> struct Carray<T, Allocator>::is_iterator
```

without semicolon at the end of the first line, just a guess.

Comment: @nightcracker: yes I did many times, but rarely had errors. I just translated what the compiler said.... No problem indeed :)

Comment: And what would `template<class T, class Allocator>;` mean?